# .htaccess Rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are already a ton of these questions but I don't get it...

I'm trying to rewrite my /register.php to /register but I can't.

.htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php [L]
```

Does any of you know the answer?

Sorry for the stupid question but I'm kinda new to the whole .htaccess stuff...

Comment: What URL are you loading that makes you think this isn't working?

Comment: @user3065852: What is the location of above .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enabled the Apache module **mod_rewrite**?

I use this pattern to create user-friendly URLs. It's pretty variable. It means, that every address in format letters-numbers with a certain file extension (PHP or HTML) will be translate into `letters-numbers.php` (for example).

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)\.(php|html)$ /$1-$2.$3 [L]
```